# Markov's matrix into stationary Distribution

Tags: probability, markov-chains

How do I know if this Markov's Transition Matrix converges into a stationary distribution?

$$P= 
\begin{bmatrix}
.8 & .2  & 0 \\
.3  & .4 & .3 \\
.2 & .1 & .7 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An irreductible aperiodic chain on a finite nomber of states $0, 1, \dots , N-1$ it's positive recurrent and is transition matrix is

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P^{(n)}= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\pi_0 & \pi_1 & \dots & \pi_{N-1}\\
\vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\pi_0 & \pi_1 & \dots & \pi_{N-1} \\
\end{bmatrix},$$

where $(\pi_0, \pi_1, \dots, \pi_{N-1})$ is the stationnary distribution which is given by the identity $\pi_j = \mu_j^{-1}$ for $j=0, 1, \dots , N-1$

**Definition :** For any positive recurrent j, the quantity $\mu_j^{-1}$ is the average fraction of a long-term $j$ visits from the initial state $j$.

Otherwise, a finite or infinite countable $\pi = (\pi_j)$ is named a *stationnary distribution* pour an irreductible chain, therefore with one class of states, if and only if the following condition are satisfied :

1. $\pi_j > 0$ for all $j$;
2. $\sum_j \pi_j=1$; and
3. $\sum_i \pi_i P_{ij}$ for all $j$, i.e. $\pi = \pi P$ in matrix notation.

The conditions $1$ and $2$ ensure that $\pi_j$ is a probability distribution strictly positive, while the condition $c$ represent the *stationnarity equation*.

**Conclusion :** In general, you could find the stationnary distribution in using  $\mu_j^{-1}$ with ergodic theorem or the condition **1**, **2** and **3** .

Comment: What does $\mu_j$ represent?

Comment: Is stationnary distribution the same as steady station distribution?

Comment: BTW, I have modified the answer to response the first question. What do you define as "steady station distribution"?

Comment: Thank you. I have found the answer to the second question here. https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~venkatg/teaching/CStheory-infoage/book-chapter-5.pdf These two terms are the same thing. I learned it as steady state distribution.